# "Dominates" in a positive manner

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, vocabulary

I want to use the word "dominates" in a positive context.

Basically, I'm writing about a movie which is influenced by a certain culture. In this context, I want to write that this culture dominates the first half of the movie. However, the word "dominates" can be taken negatively, hence I'm searching for another word.

P.S. I don't want to use the word "influenced" because I'm already using it in a previous sentence and I would like to avoid repetition.

Comment: Are you sure that 'dominates' would in fact be taken negatively ... it depends on context, I think. Maybe you can include the whole sentence in your question?

Comment: Dominates is much stronger in meaning than influences.

Comment: You probably mean *predominate*.

Comment: @Kris Would you add that as an answer? I don't know why I didn't think of it. Thanks a lot !

Comment: 'Permeates' gives the impression of being full of it.

Answer (score 1):

This culture **profoundly/largely/actively** **shapes** the first half of the movie.

Answer (score 0):

This culture **[towers](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tower)** over the first half of the movie.

> 3. To demonstrate great superiority; be preeminent: